# Ruby: Why can't a apply an operator to an instance variable?

Tags: ruby, class

Why can't I apply an operator to an instance variable using it's attr_accessor or attr_writer?. If I try to run this code:

```
class Numbers
  attr_accessor :number1

  def initialize
    @number1 = 15
  end

  def subtract
    number1 -= 1
    p number1
  end
end

num = Numbers.new
num.subtract
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from ex.rb:15:in `<main>'
ex.rb:9:in `subtract': undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

My question, how could I subtract a number from @number1 without having to explicitly putting the @, just calling the attribute.

Comment: You should post the actual code having the issue or the actual error message for the code posted. The code you posted is for `Numbers#subtract` but the error is for `#sum2`. This creates confusion in your post and while the current issue at hand is reasonably trivial without seeing the error for `subtract` or the code for `sum2` all assistance will be guess work.

Comment: Do you notice anything different between your use of `@number1` in `initialize` and your use of `number1` in `subtract`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an instance variable here it is a local one:

```
def subtract
  number1 -= 1
  p number1
end
```

To call an instance variable without `@` use `self.number1`.

```
def subtract
  self.number1 -= 1
  p number1
end
```

Comment: You don't need `self` when calling. You do need `self` when assigning. Since `-=` is an assignment operator `self` is needed here.

Comment: Sure. Good notice.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right as it stands: `number1` isn't a local variable as it would call the method defined by `attr_accessor`. You need `self` for the assignment, but you could still do, for example: `def wow; p number1 + 1; end` and it would work.

Comment: Here `-=` operator creates a local variable on the fly. If you try in `irb` `myvar -= 1` you'll get the same error, if you call `myvar` after that you'll get `nil`.

Comment: @SRack: Local variables are defined *at parse time*, as soon as an assignment is parsed. Since `number1 -= 1` is an assignment, `number1` will, *at parse time* defined to be a local variable, and thus when the method is execute *at runtime*, `number1` will always be a local variable, and never a message send.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. Thanks both :) Learned something new today.